# Create signed Git tag

Tags: git, github, encryption, gnupg

I am trying to use [gpgit](https://github.com/NicoHood/gpgit#introduction) for encrypting my github repo . I encountered the following error

```
 error: gpg failed to sign the data

 error: unable to sign the tag
```

I have surfed through the github documents and executed the command to create github tag .

```
git tag -s 1.0.0
```

This opens a page where i entered the tag as 1.0.0. After saving adn closing the window, I got the following error in the command prompt

> fatal: no tag message?

Any insights about this ? Somone tried using gpgit ? Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: gpgit doesn't encrypt your repo. The documentation and the messages clearly state that it is being signed. A digital signature doesn't provide confidetiality of the repo. It simply provides authenticity. The code can be read by anyone who has access to the repo including the service provider where you push the commits to.

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for the info !  I would like to have it signed . Any clue, why this error persist ?

Comment: @arunprakashpj `git tag -s` uses `gpg` to do the signing. Your installation of `gpg` is probably not configured. Fix that, then `git tag -s` should work.

Comment: I have already configured using the command git config --global commit.gpgsign true @Schwern

Comment: @arunprakashpj You have to make sure `gpg` is working and able to sign things. This does not involve Git. For example, have you set up a private key?

Comment: yea , i did setup the private key!  @Schwern

Comment: I solved the issue by reconfiguring my gpg @Schwern Thanks everyone !!